How to include OpenXLSX in a library with CMake
I'm trying to make use of the OpenXLSX in my c++ project.
I added the source code with a git submodule using command
git submodule add git@github.com:troldal/OpenXLSX.git external/OpenXLSX


which roughly results in the following project structure:
-CMakeLists.txt
-app/
 -- app.cpp
-src/
 --io/
  ---input.cpp
  ---CMakeLists.txt
-include/
 --io/
  ---input.hpp
-external/OpenXLSX

As suggest in OpenXLSX, in my root CmakeLists.txt I then included the directory:
# The external library code is here
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external)
add_subdirectory(external/OpenXLSX)

This was sufficient to compile the app.cpp, where the app.cpp includes OpenXLS.hpp and makes use of it.
Problem
Unfortunately this is not the desired workflow. I wish to add the OpenXLSX to my library called io.
I tried that by modifying the src/input/CMakeLists.txt which after my attempt reads
# Optionally glob, but only for CMake 3.12 or later:
set(HEADER_LIST "${MyProject_SOURCE_DIR}/include/io/input.hpp")
# Make an automatic library - will be static or dynamic based on user setting
add_library(io input.cpp ${HEADER_LIST})
# We need this directory, and users of our library will need it too
target_include_directories(io PUBLIC ../../include ../../external/*) # ----------> Added the "external" here
## This depends on (header only)
target_link_libraries(io PUBLIC spdlog::spdlog  OpenXLSX::OpenXLSX) # -----> Added OpenXLSX::OpenXLSX library here
# All users of this library will need at least C++17
target_compile_features(io PUBLIC cxx_std_17)

# IDEs should put the headers in a nice place
source_group(
        TREE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
        PREFIX "Header Files"
        FILES ${HEADER_LIST})


But when I try to #include <OpenXLSX.hpp> in include/io/input.hpp the compiler says
[ 80%] Building CXX object src/parts/CMakeFiles/wing.dir/airfoil.cpp.o
In file included from /home/me/Documents/MyProject/src/mesh/../../include/parts/wing.hpp:8,
                 from /home/me/Documents/MyProject/src/mesh/../../include/mesh/mesh.hpp:10,
                 from /home/me/Documents/MyProject/src/mesh/mesh.cpp:5:
/home/me/Documents/MyProject/src/mesh/../../include/io/input.hpp:13:10: fatal error: OpenXLSX.hpp: No such file or directory
   13 | #include <OpenXLSX.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/me/Documents/MyProject/src/io/input.cpp:7:
/home/me/Documents/MyProject/src/io/../../include/io/input.hpp:13:10: fatal error: OpenXLSX.hpp: No such file or directory
   13 | #include <OpenXLSX.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```.

I can't figure out how to solve this thing. What anybody know what I am doing wrong?


That ../../external/* does nothing. It does not get expanded like you think it would.

Please add the full error output and CMakeLists.txt leading to it: do you see this error when compiling the io target or rather some target that depends on a header of io?

@Botje I added some more of the output. But, good point. The error is actually thrown while building some other target depending on io.

@Botje  Oh OK, I see. I just randomly added OpenXLSX::OpenXLSXto other targets and now it works. Thanks for the hint. YOu may want to submit an answer.

The error clearly states this is during the building of the wing target. OpenXLSX is a public dependency of io so linking wing to io should be sufficient.
